# Suggestions for choosing between two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Two pieces of jQuery code below (1) (2), Can someone tell which one is better and why? And should I place `myfunction` at the top or bottom? I have been seeing both in many answers on the related topics.

(1)

```
var myfunction = function () {
  // do stuff
};

$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).resize(myfunction);
```

(2)

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).on('resize',myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Forgive me if the question wasn't asked in the proper way.

Comment: (1) is (2)'s alias. `$(window).resize(myfunction)` internally calls `$(window).on('resize',myfunction);`

Comment: That's not "opinion-based" necessarily - there may be objective drawbacks and advantages to using either method (like things not possible if you do it in one of the two ways). If it's only a matter of taste, then that's also an objective answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap all my jquery undertakings into a self invoking function, and do the stuff there, for the sake of not polluting global namespace:

```js
$(function () {
  
  function myFunction() {
    console.log("doing stuff");
  }

  $(window).on("resize", myFunction);

  myFunction();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, don't forget JavaScript is camelCase preffered, so myFunction rather than myfunction :)

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery 1.7 it's recommended to use the `.on()` statements. All functions like `.click() .resize() .dblclick()` are difficult to maintain for the jQuery team. (They are all fragmented, now it's all in 1 function)

`.on()` is the newest version, so this is also the one the developers are going to maintain. It's not sure if the developers will maintain the other functions (see my examples) in further updates.

Of course they will in the coming ones, but it's not sure for how long.

Comment: on was added to allow for custom events, not to sunset jquery direct methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a matter of taste. I prefer the shortcut bindings like `resize` instead of just `on`, because it saves me some keystrokes and makes the code prettier.

About where to declare the functions it doesn't make difference in this particular case (in terms of execution) because of something called [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

In terms of readability, I recommend you to read [this post](http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-function-declarations-function-expressions-and-readable-code/), that makes a good point in using this feature to make your code more clear.

Comment: on was added to allow parameterization of events and is used for custom events. It's use is not taste but specific use case based. There is nothing flippant about jquery's method set.

Comment: i'm obviously talking about the cases where a shortcut is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a function a var implies scope. In the following example, the function myFunction enters ram, and then is destroyed when the parent is destroyed.

```
myParentFunction = function(){
    var myfunction = function () {
      // do stuff
    };
}
```

If it's sitting on Window, then no scope is needed. Functions are parsed on load before code is run and it doesn't matter where they appear.

For the rest... jquery "on" is usually used when you want to make the event a parameter. Otherwise assigning it directly is fine.

Comment: that's not true, because regular shortcut handlers can also receive the event as a parameter. the biggest difference is that you can use ```on``` for delegated events. that means you can capture events of an element's children without binding handlers directly to them. this is useful, for example, when you have a table with 1000 lines and want to use just one handler instead of 1000.